# I want to change UITextView's font size

Tags: iphone, ios

I have used UITextView in my application. Now this might be a dumb question but how can I change the font size of text in it.

if any1 can help with this would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: how u want to change by coding or at designing time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
[yourtextview setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f]];
```

Comment: .setFont method is used inside bracket.

Answer (score 7):

you have to set font by code

```
yourtextViewObject.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITextView` has a read-write `font` property declared:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIFont *font;
```

The `UIFont` class declares a factory method:

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize;
```

So create a new `UIFont` instance and then call `-setFont:` on your `UITextView` with the font instance.